# how does Thunar generate thumbnails?

Tags: thunar, thumbnails

How does Thunar generate thumbnails? Does it generate them themself or does it use some external tool?

Comment: I think it is clear what is being asked here: does Thunar generate thumbnails themself or does it use some external tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thunar` internally uses `tumbler` for the thumbnail generation. `Tumbler` is a `d-bus` service for applications to request thumbnails for different MIME types.

Answer (score 1):

Thunar uses [tumbler](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler) to generate thumbnails.